# Rate of increase of maximum process of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose $M_t=\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\{B_s\}$, where $\{B_t\}_0^{\infty}$ is a standard Brownian Motion. I would like to know if it is true that $M_t e^{-t}$ converges to 0 almost surely?

Thanks!

Comment: taking expectations shows $\sum_n M_n e^{-n} < \infty $, and  it should be straightforward although  maybe not easy to deal with the difference between integers and reals.

Comment: Yes, I think I am able to show that $M_t e^{-t}$ converges to 0 in $L^1$ because each $M_t$ has the same distribution as $|B_t|$, but pointwise convergence seems a more difficult question.

Comment: my argument implies pt wise convergence of $M_n e^{-n}$ to $0$ because it is implied by $\sum M_n e^{-n} < \infty, (n^{th}$ term goes to $0$), but on second thought, you ought to be able to get it from $\frac {B_t}t \rightarrow 0 $.

Comment: Yea, thanks. I've already got it.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed just follows from reflection principle and Borel-Cantelli

$$\sum_n P[M_{t_{n}}\frac{1}{g(t_{n})}\geq \epsilon]=\sum_n P[|B_{t_{n}}|\geq g(t_{n})\epsilon]\leq c \sum_{n}exp(-\frac{(g(t_{n}))^{2}}{2t_{n}}),$$

so any diverging sequence $g(t_{n})$ that makes this sum finite, will give the a.s.-limit to be zero.